# External CSS file won't affect button styles

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

For example, I have the following button:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg register_btn rounded-0 submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

and the following code in a custom `custom.css` file:

```
.submit-button {    
    background-color:yellow!important;
    border-color:yellow!important;
}
```

But it won't affect the color of the button. but if I do an inline style for the button it works

This is how I include the Bootstrap file and `custom.css`:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/custom.css">
```

Comment: Are you linking custom.css file after linking bootstrap?

Comment: yes it's one line under the bootstrap include, edited post to show you how

Comment: Sounds like a specificity or cascade issue.

Comment: @pileup: Have voted for you, just to welcome you into the coding world and to boost your moral and confidence. U are in the initial stage of coding. Give it a best shot. "Learning comes with practice and a disciplinary one" Best wishes to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is missing in `yellow!important.` between `yellow` and `!important`. Give space after `yellow` or Copy below code and replace your old code with this one and Try:)

```
.submit-button {    
    background-color:yellow !important;
    border-color:yellow !important;
}
```

**Note**: Do make sure your `custom.css` file is in css folder and linked correctly. Do a Developer window check once in your Browser(`Ctrl+SHift+I`) to see what CSS is applied on the button.

**UPDATE:**

Since this is spacing issue, you can avoid `!important` now as it is not a good practice. And so make sure no inline style is used  :)

```
.submit-button {    
    background-color:yellow;
    border-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Yes! And I thought it was supposed to be without space (I'm a beginner). Thank you!

Comment: And yes. You can avoid !important all together. This will work fine without it as well

Answer (score 0):

As seen is that you entered the correct code and the class correctly. The only thing that could have happened was that you did not call the file custom.css right in your head tag. That is, it does not find the source to make the changes at all
you can use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="direction/custom.css">` in `<head>`